# how to return url in form file in strut

Tags: struts2

hai all,

i have one problem regarding to return the form file value is validation fail. i have one form that have a few field to be fullfil by the user and one attachment field.if one of the field is blank the system will give the error when submit the form..my problem is, all the field will have the value that we entered before this but for form file it disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand your issue: You  have a form with several input fields, and among them a `<input type=file>` for uploading some file content. In case of validation error, you return to that page (with struts2 result = INPUT, I guess) and the content of the previously filled fields  appears, except for the FILE field.

This makes sense, if you understand how the other fields are "refilled" in Struts2 in this scenario (just from the action, which has typically mapped the parameters to properties). The server doesnt know the (clientside) fullpath of the file, it is not sent along the http request (it would be a privacy issue), it's the content of the file what is uploaded (and perhaps the filename without path). You can't escape that.

Anyway, I think this a case in which validation should signal an error early (in javascript, in the client side). Think about it: the user is uploading a file (potentially large) together with other info, and AFTER uploading it the server checks the fields and instructs the user to refill the fields and retry (including the upload). This can be unacceptable. My advise is, then, to include client-side validation (and if it pass, and the server validation fails, then the user must resign to refill the FILE field). If the file is large, one could split the input form in two pages, a first one to fill the several fields, and afterwards another to upload the file.